# Especificar condición conjunta y excluyente de columnas con WHERE múltiples veces

Tags: mysql, sql

Pues estoy utilizando MYSQL y no consigo especificar unas columnas especificas múltiples veces. Se que el código siguiente esta mal pero es para entender mejor lo que intento hacer.

Nota: id_seguir_libro = id del libro

Necesito especificar en la misma consulta, que de `id_seguir_libro` seleccione unos id en especifico y con unos capítulos concretos. Con IN no me sirve, porque seleccionaría los id de seguir los libros bien, pero entonces no cogería los capítulos correctos para cada seguimiento. Puede que el usuario no este siguiendo un libro o `id_seguir_libro`, puede incluso que no este siguiendo ninguno. Lo que intento es que devuelva los que si esta siguiendo

```
SELECT id_seguir_libro, numero_capitulo
FROM Seguir, Capitulos
WHERE id_usuario = 1 AND
id_seguir_libro = id_libro_capitulo AND
(id_seguir_libro = 15 AND numero_capitulo = (10+1)) AND/OR
(id_seguir_libro = 25 AND numero_capitulo = (5+1)) AND/OR
(id_seguir_libro = 30 AND numero_capitulo = (23+1))
```

También he probado hacerlo con CASE WHEN, pero tampoco sale.

Comment: Prueba esta consulta: `SELECT id_libro, numero_capitulo
FROM Libros l
INNER JOIN Capitulos c ON l.id_libro=c.id_libro_capitulo
WHERE 
 l.id_usuario = 1 AND
 (l.id_libro = 15 AND c.numero_capitulo = 11) OR
    (l.id_libro = 25 AND c.numero_capitulo = 6 ) OR
    (l.id_libro = 30 AND c.numero_capitulo = 24`  no entiendo por qué sumas valores cuando los puedes poner direcramente ¿?

Comment: Pero no explicas con claridad lo que quieres. Inicialmente lo que se entendía era que querías los libros / capítulos con las diferentes condiciones que aparecen en la consulta. Luego, has agregado una nueva columna que antes no aparecía. Sería bueno que pongas un ejemplo breve de lo que quieres obtener y mejores el planteamiento de la pregunta aportando un poco más de claridad. Gracias.

Comment: no he agregado una nueva columna simplemente le he cambiado de nombre para que se entienda mejor

Answer (score 1):

Prueba tu consulta de esta manera:

```
SELECT 
    c.id_usuario,
    l.id_libro,
    c.numero_capitulo
FROM libros l 
    INNER JOIN capitulos c ON l.id_libro=c.id_libro_capitulo
WHERE 
    c.id_usuario = 1 AND -- asumo que esta columna es de la tabla capitulo
    (l.id_libro = 1 AND c.numero_capitulo = 10+1) OR 
    (l.id_libro = 2 AND c.numero_capitulo = 5+1 ) OR 
    (l.id_libro = 3 AND c.numero_capitulo = 23+1) ;
```

Aunque realmente no sé por qué haces una suma de valores y no pones directamente `11,6,24`.

Hice una prueba de concepto con la consulta como indicada más arriba, por motivos de brevedad usé los id_libro 1,2,3 en los datos de prueba, para no tener que insertar hasta 30 libros...

**<kbd>[VER DEMOSTRACIÓN CON DATOS REALES](http://rextester.com/JHJOC16412)</kbd>**

Este es el resultado:

```
usuario_id    libro_id     capitulo_no
----------------------------------------
    1          2               6
    1          1               11
    1          3               24
```

Comment: No funcona, y la suma són variables, o sea que seria como X o ? Falla cuando el id_libro por ejemplo el id_libro 15 si que debe meterlo pero el 25 no debería pero falla y lo pone igual. Si alguno que no debe poner esta entre medias de las que si que debe meter  o el ultimo entonces lo pone igual.

Comment: he editado la pregunta, para dar más información, lo que pasa con tu respuesta es que en caso de que el usuario no este siguiendo dicha obra, en tu caso id_libro o en la corrección id_seguir_libro, la pone igual.

Comment: ¿El libro 15 debe mételo y el 25 no? ¿Entonces por qué pones en el `WHERE` el libro 25 si hay que ignorar ese libro? @Menzezzz

Comment: Exacto. Quizás no tendría que ir en el WHERE, yo lo que intento es comprobar esos libros y que me devuelva el que si esta siguiendo de entre esos libros  @A. Cedano

Comment: @Menzezzz todavía no entiendo. ¿Quizá no necesites incluir en el `WHERE` la información relativa al libro quedando la consulta así: ... `WHERE 
    c.id_usuario = 1 AND  c.numero_capitulo = 10+1` ...? Sin conocer tu estructura de datos y lo que quieres con claridad, todo lo que se haga será aventurarse en respuestas que quizá no resuelvan el problema.